# What is the difference between process, activity, workflow, project and robot?

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-studio

currently i'm taking the "RPA Developer Foundation" course on UiPath.
This my first time learning about RPA and UiPath. I’m really confused about some terms. I’m confused about the difference between Process, activity, workflow, project and robot.
Please tell me if i’m wrong, the project is the robot itself and it contains multiple workflows and each workflow contains multiple activities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **robot** can interact with processes.

A **project** contains meta information about a process.

A **process** can have 0 or endless workflows.

A **workflow** can have 0 or endless activities.

An **activity** is a specific (and often predefined) command.